# How do you post form data and files using Ajax in asp.net.core?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have this html form which I want to post data and files to C# Web Api. Here is my front-end code

```js
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var input = document.getElementById('files');

        var files = input.files;

        var formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("files", files[i]);
        }

        var tags = $('#tags').val();

        formData.append("tags", tags);
    
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "https://localhost:44371/api/file/upload",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {
                    alert("Files Uploaded!");
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="upload-button">
        <input id="files" name="files" type="file" size="1" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tags">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Upload and Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is my back-end Web Api C# code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<FileDocument>> PostFileDocument(List<IFormFile> files, string tags)
    {
        return Ok("test");
        
    }
```

I can reach this method and I can see `files` has data. But `tags` is showing null. But I have appended `tags` at `formData.append("tags", tags);`. I googled and some said put `[FromBody] List<IFormFile> files` which I have tried but when I did, it became null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read, but not tried myself, that it works by creating a class to be used as the parameter of `PostFileDocument()`. This class would have an array of `IFormFile` and a string property for the tags as in

```cs
class SomeController 
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<FileDocument>> PostFileDocument([FromForm]Payload payload)
    {
        // some nice code here
    }
}

class Payload 
{
    // You probably have to align the naming of what you `append()`
    // to the `FormData` in JavaScript (e.g. `formData.append("Files", ...)`
    // instead of `formData.append("files", ...)`). 
    public IFormFile[] Files {get;set;}
    public string Tags {get;set;}
}
```

This is described here: https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/09/04/handling-multipart-requests-with-json-and-file-uploads-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Any collection type for `files` is fine - it doesn't have to be an array. The JS just needs to prefix each `FormData` key with `payload.` for it to bind (e.g. `payload.files`). Alternatively, just using `[FromForm] string tags` will also work.